# How to deal with question that is essentially the same question but about a different model of coffee machine?

Tags: discussion

I recently answered a [question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/foam-knife-one-on-breville-dual-boiler/3338#3338) about fitting a specific steam tip on to the Breville Dual Boiler.

The user linked the steam tip in question which described the threading to be 1/8" female British Standard size thread. He accepted the answer and moved onto to ask the [same question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/foam-knife-one-on-delonghi-ec155) about another coffee machine.

Surely he could continue asking the question and cascade through all the possible variations of it and judging by his re-ask, he hasn't done any research of his own into the coffee machines he is interested in.

How do we deal with questions like these where they are essentially duplicates born from lack of research?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for highlighting this. In general, putting in policy for this sort of thing is not necessary, unless it becomes a regular issue. In general if you see user behaviour of any kind that you think could be a problem, just raise a custom flag on one of their posts explaining the situation and a mod will deal with the situation. We have better tools and visibility on other activity to know if this is a one-off coincidence or a deliberate attempt to rep-farm.